# Word for a task that is necessary, tiresome, and accustomed to?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes a task or act that you recognise and are accustomed to, but a "familiar task" had a positive colouring which doesn't quite capture what I'm aiming for.

In context, I want the word for a morning ritual which a girl has gone through her entire life, but takes no pleasure in doing so. Specifically, a cold and piercing morning shower to refresh herself.

> "For a while, she confides in the familiar, mellow warmth of her bedsheets, but she knows she must get up. Her first choice is the shower, a ___________ that she knows she must do."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not clear whether the OP wants a word to describe a feeling or a task.

The morning ritual -- the cold shower -- which the young girl must perform is a **chore**.  The feeling she has about it is ***resignation***, [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/resignation)

> the feeling of a person who is prepared to accept something unpleasant

Example to fit the OP's question:

> She approached the **chore** of her early morning cold shower with
>   **resignation**.

***chore*** as defined by [Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/chore):

> a job or piece of work that needs to be done regularly:
>
> By the time he’d finished all the household chores it was
>   mid-afternoon.
>
> A chore is also something that is difficult and unpleasant:
>
> It was a real chore trying to give our dog a bath.

Comment: I apologise, I was not specific enough. Both are ideal, although I was looking for the word for the task. Many thanks!

Comment: It depends on the level of displeasure in my opinion. A **chore** could become an **ordeal**, or perhaps even **torture** depending on the level of dislike. If it wasn't actually physically obnoxious, it could also be the **tedium** of the task, although tedium could also become an ordeal or torture over time..

Comment: @TajwarQurashy You may want to edit your question. In your original question, you state that you are "looking for a word that describes a **feeling**..."